# How is the HL7 CDR component represented/implemented?

Tags: hl7

I'm new to `HL7` and I'm trying to figure out how to represent the PID segment - namely PID-5-10.  PID-5-10 is the "CDR component" and it consists of 2 sub-components each made up of 2 values - `Time and Degree of Precision`. If I look at the standard separators defined in the MSH-2 it appears that there aren't enough separators to differentiate the `Time and Degree of Precision` values.

e.g.

```
PID|1|2|3|4|5-1^^^^^^^^^5-10-1.Time?5-10-1.Precision&5-10-2.Time?5-10-1.Precision^5.11
```

What's the standard separator I should use in place of the '?' in the above example?
Any insight and assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: What documentation is pointing you in this direction?  PID5 is for the patient name.  A quick Google search on HL7 PID CDR come back to this question - which leads me to believe that you may be placing the time components in the wrong segment.

Comment: I'm looking at the standard, working on a parser, and trying to understand how HL7 represents elements _like_ PID-5-10-1.time and PID-5-10-1.Precision in a segment.  We may never receive or need to send values for these elements, but they're described in the standard and I'm trying to understand how HL7 supports these sub-subcomponents when there doesn't appear to be a separator defined for them.

Comment: Do you have a link to the standard you are using?  PID.5 is of type XPN which in version 2.3 is specifically <family name (FN)> ^ <given name (ST)> ^ <second and further given names or initials thereof (ST)> ^ <suffix (e.g., JR or III) (ST)> ^ <prefix (e.g., DR) (ST)> ^ <degree (e.g., MD) (IS)> ^ <name type code (ID) > ^ <name representation code (ID)> ^ <name context (CE)> ^ <name validity range (DR)> ^ <name assembly order (ID)>   I'm not questioning your intent, I'm just suspect of the documentation that you're working off of.

Answer (score 1):

PID 5 is the patient name.  Which is typically no more than

> |last^first^mid^suffix^prefix|

Comment: Feel free to add this to the proposed list of questions at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it